# Why is my linked list printing backwards?

Tags: c, data-structures, printing, linked-list, insert

I would like to print the contents of my linked list, which come from a file, as follows:

```
1,Postit Notes,Sticky notes,3
2,Black pens,Gel pens with black ink,5
3,Blue pens, Gel pens with blue ink, 4
4, Red pens, Gel pens with red ink for grading, 3
5, Notecards,Ruled 3" by 5" notecards,2
7,Whiteout,For mistakes made when writting with ink,3
```

Thus far in my program, my input is being read in correctly, and I have debugged that portion, so I know that is not the issue. I am having issues with printing my linked list.

I have tried to write an `addRecord` method (shown below) in which I allocate memory for a new node, assign in the data it requires, and attempt to add it add the end of the linked list. I also have a method to print the contents of the linked list, all shown below:

```
static void *addRecord(List *list, int newID, char *newName, char *newSummary, int newCount) 
{
  //Allocate memory for the node
  Node *new = (Node *)malloc(sizeof(Node)); 

  //Add in data
  new->id = newID;
  strcpy(new->name, newName);
  strcpy(new->summary, newSummary);
  new->count = newCount;

  //Node gets data you added in
  new->next = list->head;
  list->head = new;
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

```
void print(List *list)
{
  printf("LIST IN FORWARD ORDER:\n");

  //Create a temporary node to traverse the list
  Node *temp = list->head;

  //Traverse the entire list
  while (temp != NULL) {
    printf("Item ID: %d\n", temp->id);
    printf("Name: %s\n", temp->name);
    printf("Summary: %s\n", temp->summary);
    printf("Count: %d\n", temp->count);
    printf("-----\n");
    temp = temp->next;
  }
}
```

Here is how my linked list is set up:

```
//struct for each office item
struct NodeStruct {
    int id;
    char name[MAX_NAME];
    char summary[MAX_SUM];
    int count;
    struct NodeStruct *next;
};


/** Structure for the whole list, including head and tail pointers. */
typedef struct {
  /** Pointer to the first node on the list (or NULL ). */
  Node *head;
} List;
```

My expected output should look like this:

```
LIST IN FORWARD ORDER:
Item ID: 1
Name: Postit Notes
Summary: Sticky notes
Count: 3
-----
Item ID: 2
Name: Black pens
Summary: Gel pens with black ink
Count: 5
-----
Item ID: 3
Name: Blue pens
Summary: Gel pens with blue ink
Count: 4
-----
Item ID: 4
Name: Red pens
Summary: Gel pens with red ink for grading
Count: 3
-----
Item ID: 5
Name: Notecards
Summary: Ruled 3" by 5" notecards
Count: 2
-----
Item ID: 7
Name: Whiteout
Summary: For mistakes made when writting with ink
Count: 3
-----
```

However, my actual output is:

```
LIST IN FORWARD ORDER:
Item ID: 7
Name: Whiteout
Summary: For mistakes made when writting with ink
Count: 3
-----
Item ID: 5
Name:  Notecards
Summary: Ruled 3" by 5" notecards
Count: 2
-----
Item ID: 4
Name:  Red pens
Summary:  Gel pens with red ink for grading
Count: 3
-----
Item ID: 3
Name: Blue pens
Summary:  Gel pens with blue ink
Count: 4
-----
Item ID: 2
Name: Black pens
Summary: Gel pens with black ink
Count: 5
-----
Item ID: 1
Name: Postit Notes
Summary: Sticky notes
Count: 3
-----
```

In my print method, when I try to print the contents of the head node, I get the data/information from the item with ID 7, when I should get the information for the item with ID 1. Could someone explain to my why my list is printing backwards? I am trying to trace it, but I am kind of confused. I have tried other ways to add the record in, but I keep getting `Segmentation Fault: 11` when I try to do so.

Thank you in advance!

EDIT:

After Thomas Jager's comment below, I made the following modification to my addRecord method:

```
static void *addRecord(List *list, int newID, char *newName, char *newSummary, int newCount) 
{
  //Allocate memory for the node
  Node *new = (Node *)malloc(sizeof(Node)); 

  //Add in data
  new->id = newID;
  strcpy(new->name, newName);
  strcpy(new->summary, newSummary);
  new->count = newCount;

  //Special case: If the first node is null, add the data here
  if (list->head->next == NULL) {
    list->head->next = new;
  } else {
    Node *temp = new; 
    while (temp != NULL) {
      new = new->next; 
    }
  }

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

However, now, I get the following error:

```
Segmentation fault: 11
```

I am having trouble understanding the segmentation fault error that occurred, could someone please explain it to me?

Comment: When you add to the list, you're adding to the front of the list. It's not printing backwards, it is backwards.

Comment: If you want to add to the tail of the list, you need to maintain the tail of the list in the `List` struct. Add `Node *tail;` right after `Node *head;`, and update the `tail` pointer in `addRecord`. Ylou might want to be able to add to the head or to the tail. This is a nice exercise.

Comment: Hi @ThomasJager, thanks so much for pointing that out. Could you please look at my edit to the question above, as I am still getting some errors and am not sure what I am doing wrong to cause a segmentation fault?

Comment: @PomegranateSociety In your modified code, you access `new->next` which is almost definitely some garbage value. You want to do something similar, but go through the existing list's `next` values, not the `new`'s. see my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is in the way you add to your list. You always add at the head instead of the tail of your list.

One way to fix this is to change your `addRecord` function:

```
static void addRecord(List *list, int newID, char *newName, char *newSummary, int newCount) 
{
  //Allocate memory for the node
  Node *new = malloc(sizeof(Node));

  //Add in data
  new->id = newID;
  strcpy(new->name, newName);
  strcpy(new->summary, newSummary);
  new->count = newCount;

  //New node has no next, yet
  new->next = NULL;

  //Add new node to the end of the list
  Node **next_p = &list->head;
  while (*next_p)
    next_p = &(*next_p)->next;
  *next_p = new;
}
```

There are many ways of adding to the tail of the list. The way I chose here uses a pointer to a `Node *`. This allows the `head` in `List` and `next` in `Node` to be represented in the same way.

Another way of doing it is slightly less elegant, but more readable. Avoiding this double pointer could be done like you've done in your edited question, but modified to go through the list's `next`s:

```
  //Add new node to the end of the list
  if (!list->head->next) {
    list->head->next = new;
  } else {
    Node *temp = list->head->next; 
    while (temp->next) {
      temp = temp->next; 
    }
    temp->next = new;
  }
```

Both cases require that the initial `list->head` is `NULL`, but it seems like that's already the case, given your printing.

There are a couple additional things I changed. You shouldn't cast the return value of `malloc` in C. Also, your `addRecord` had return type `void *`, and you return `EXIT_SUCCESS`. If you're trying to return a success value, `void *` likely isn't the right way of doing this.

Comment: The while loop is totally inefficient. Imagine the list has one million entries.

Comment: @Jabberwocky This fixes the issue that they're having with insertions happening at the beginning instead of the end. Efficient data structures, even just keeping a pointer to the last entry, are separate issues.

Comment: Maintaining a `tail` pointer in addition to the `head` pointer, will most likely be even simpler that your solution, and of course more efficient.